# Can't open Assembly-CSharp properties. Instantly closes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to change the root namespace on my project, which lives in the properties. Whenever I try open  **Assembly-CSharp properties** though, any scripts I have open will briefly flash blank and then nothing will happen. There's no error or signs it tried beyond that flash. I have no idea what to try.

Worth noting, this happen both from the project tab, and right clicking the assembly file in the solution explorer. This is also as a part of a Unity project, should that for some reason matter. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and it's fully up to date.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend was able to find the answer for me on this one. It turns out, **Tools for Unity** disablest the ability to access the properties.

To disable this go to **Settings >> Tools for Unity >> General >> Miscellaneous >> Access to project properties**

It turns out though, you don't need to do this anyways. I was mistaken that you need to do this in the Unity settings and the VS settings seperately, but VS will read from Unity. It's disabled because Unity will handle the project settings so they are set as expected for Unity use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the root namespace of a Unity project, I suggest you do it via the Editor : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EditorManager.html

If you have already done so, the rest might depend on your IDE. In any case, I suggest you check this out : [How to change root namespace in unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/187802/how-can-i-change-the-root-namespace-for-scripts-in-unityhttps://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/187802/how-can-i-change-the-root-namespace-for-scripts-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Visual Studio 2019` as well and it happens there. It is a bug and it is easy to workaround it.

After getting the blank screen there are several easy workarounds you can do:

1. Click on any other class and open it and then return back to the blank screen (it shouldn't be blank anymore).
2. If the Solution Explorer is opened to you, you can change its size with the mouse, when you will change the size it will immediately show the page.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem like the same bug. No window appears, at least as far as I can tell. It just makes any classes I do have open flash blank for a second. If I close them all then try, you don't see anything at all.